# npm next dev is not starting server

Tags: npm, next.js, npm-scripts

I'm trying the 'npm next dev' command and it's not starting the server. instead it spits out the following. Does anyone know what the issue is?

---

$ npm next dev

Usage: npm

where  is one of:
access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
edit, explore, fund, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
whoami

npm  -h  quick help on 
npm -l            display full usage info
npm help    search for help on 
npm help npm      involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
C:\Users\Nick.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm  --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@6.14.12 C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\npm

Did you mean one of these?
get
set
test

---

I cd'd into the dir, ran npm install for dependancies, and then ran npm next dev to start the dev server and got the above output.

Answer (score 0):

To start the Next.js development server, run the following command:

`npm run dev`

This command will start the Next.js server in development mode. It will compile your code and provide a local development URL (usually http://localhost:3000) where you can access your Next.js application.